# SQL: How to store and link huge amounts of data from tests

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have **multiple tests** where **each** created a **big set of data** (ten thousands of values).
I want to create a table that holds all the tests and links each one to its data.
The data should be easily accessible to manipulate it (current approach is a CSV file as string and is really bad).
Which of these solutions is the best? (or is there an even better one)

- store all results in a table together with the test number
    `+-------+---------+`
  `| test1 | result1 |`
  `+-------+---------+`
  `| test1 | result2 |`
  `+-------+---------+`
  `| test2 | result1 |`
  `+-------+---------+`
  `| ...   | ...     |`
  `+-------+---------+`
- store all results of one test in a separate table with the test number as name
  `name: test1`     `name: test2`
  `+---------+`     `+---------+`
  `| result1 |`     `| result1 |`
  `+---------+`     `+---------+`
  `| result2 |`     `| result2 |`
  `+---------+`     `+---------+`
  `| ...     |`     `| ...     |`
  `+---------+`     `+---------+`
- store the results as a table inside of the test table (if that's even possible)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

For many reasons, the first version, with all tests residing in a single table, is probably the design choice you should make.  Here are some reasons:

- Unless you have a LOT of records (e.g. in the billions), a single table should be able to handle the data from all tests.  This could be even more true if you setup indices which make it easier to query the data.
- If you ever have the need to do any kind of reporting across multiple tests (quite likely actually), then having all tests' data in a single place will make your life much easier.  On the other hand, having each test in a separate table would mean some ugly SQL to do any kind of reporting.
- If you end up with thousands of tests, then you won't like maintaining and sifting through thousands of tables.  But maintaining a single table is not a big problem.

Answer (score 3):

I would envision two tables.  Something like this:

```
create table tests (
    testId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    name varchar(255),
    createdAt datetime default getdate()
);

create table testResults (
    testResultId int identity(1, 1) primary key,
    testid int foreign key references tests(testId),
    . . .   -- columns for the results
);
```